# in Java, How read() method from FileReader class works?

Tags: java

I have a file (h.txt) in which I wrote a letter 'h' and press Enter and I saved and closed it. I used the FileReader class to read the content of the file as follows:

```
    FileReader inf = new FileReader("h.txt");
    int chCode;
    while (-1 != (chCode = inf.read())) System.out.print("2" + (char) chCode + "1");
    inf.close();
```

The output is:

`12`

`1`

How the read() method read the characters?

In h.txt file I removed the Enter so the file contains only 'h' character and as I expected the output became:

`2h1`

However, adding Enter to the file make an unexpected result. I meant how 12 appeared?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. When h.txt contains an h and a newline, I get `2h12<newline>1`, as expected.

Comment: How is a question that doesn’t mention `BufferedReader` a duplicate of a question about it?

Comment: "However, adding Enter to the file make an unexpected result" - what result, and what did you expect?

Comment: that is not related to `read()`. but seems like your console, or whatever output being used, is interpreting the so called *Enter* as a carriage return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how the "Enter" is actually saved in the file (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) and how the console is interpreting these characters, specially when a `CRLF` sequence is split, the output can be explained like this:

We assume the content of the file are the three bytes `0x68`, `0x0d` and `0x0a`, which are the characters `h`, `\r` and `\n`. Then the `while` loop will generate the output in order:

1. `2h1`
2. `2\r1`
3. `2\n1`

If we generate the output step by step by simulating a console we will read the output `12 1` like this at the end:

First we print the first loop iteration result, that's easy:

```
2h1
   ^
```

The `^` indicate where the cursor currently is. Then we print the text `2\r1`. We split it up to print these characters individually. First the `2`:

```
2h12
    ^
```

Now we "print" the [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return), which moves the cursor to the start **without** going to the next line:

```
2h12
^
```

Now we print the remaining `1`, overriding the previous written start.

```
1h12
 ^
```

Now we print the third loop iteration result, the text `2\n1`. Again, we split the print to separate characters. First the `2` will overwrite the `h` character:

```
1212
  ^
```

Now it gets tricky. The [line feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) gets printed, but your console you are using (my guess it is the windows command line, but I could be wrong) does not recognize a single `\n` sequence as a new line, but expect such new lines to be generated with `\r\n` (CRLF). Therefore, it "prints" the character as a white space in the same line without going to the next line, overwriting the `1` at the current place:

```
12 2
   ^
```

And finally, it prints the remaining `1` character, overwriting the exist `2` character at this place:

```
12 1
   ^
```

That's how the output is generated, assuming all the assumptions I made are true. As an example, on linux it generates a different output:

```
1212
1
```

And on https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/PXR (or https://www.mycompiler.io/view/1enrA60VJkU) it generates the following output:

```
2h12
12
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Found h, write 2h1 on console,
found CR: write 2 : 2h12
then write CR :cursor goes back to the begining of Line, write 1: 1h12,
found another char , write 2 : 1212,
This char (null?) is not writable: write space in place: 12 2
,remember cursor is after Space,
write final 1 (overwriting previous 2): 12 1

I think your 'enter' put a CR while on other case it could be a LF CR or a crlf.

I can't explain 'another char' (may be your *while* is wrong and is -1 one round later. I can't test here, I am on my phone...).

That remembers me the beginning of printers in 80th where the print head goes back to beginning and overwrite previous line if only a CR...